# Automate adding symbol size expression for all layers ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, arcade, cartographic-information-model

I have many layers on a map. I need to write an Arcade expression in the symbol size expression box, but I need to do it in all the layers. I do not want to do that one by one.

I wanted to create a script that add the Arcade expression for the custom symbol size on ArcGIS Pro.
I have already done a script before that adds a query layer expression automatically using:

```
if lyr.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"):
     lyr.definitionQuery = ...
```

Obviously symbol size expression is totally different but it is still an expression that I want to add to all the layers.

Is this even possible?

I haven't found anything on forums yet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to script the setting of the symbol size using a custom expression then you need to be using the [CIM](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm) module through ArcPy and you can control the `ValueExpressionInfo`. Take note of the cautions and I would recommend you install the [CIM viewer](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk-cim-viewer) so you can see a layers properties and then understand how to navigate the CIM properties via ArcPy.